# How to get Symfony clean URL after GET request

Tags: php, symfony, request, get

I'm working on a small Symfony project and I came across an issue I don't know how to fix. I'm performing a database search via a GET request, and I'm looking for articles that are part of categories. I can select many categories and press "search", then it will return only the specific articles.

The feature is working great, but my URL isn't... "clean", I think. Working on localhost, this is what I see, for example, when I look for category "vocabulary":

```
localhost:8000/blog/?q=&categories[]=125
```

The *q* parameter is here to return articles when I look for a specific text (with an input field), but I think it shouldn't appear if the research only concerns categories. Right?

Also, display `categories[]=125` is weird. The user should see something like `categories=vocabulary&categories=grammar&categories...` or something like this (of course, trying to avoid the repetition of "categories" in the URL.

How can I do this? This is what my code looks like in the repository:

```
/**
     * Find articles related to search
     */
    public function findSearch(SearchData $search): PaginationInterface
    {
        $query = $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->select('a', 'c')
            ->join('a.categories', 'c'); 

        // Handling text search
        if (null !== $search->q && !empty($search->q)) {
            $query = $query
                ->andWhere('a.title LIKE :q')
                ->setParameter('q', "%{$search->q}%");
        }

        // Handling categories
        if (!empty($search->categories)) {
            $query = $query
                ->andWhere('c.id IN (:categories)')
                ->setParameter('categories', $search->categories);
        }

        $query = $query->getQuery();
        
        return $this->paginator->paginate(
            $query,
            $search->page,
            9
        );
    }
```

And here is what my controller looks like:

```
#[Route('/', name: 'blog_index')]
    public function index(ArticleRepository $articleRepository, Request $request): Response
    {
        $data = new SearchData();
        $data->page = $request->get('page', 1);
        $form = $this->createForm(SearchType::class, $data);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $articles = $articleRepository->findSearch($data);

        return $this->render('blog/index.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form,
            'articles' => $articles,
        ]);
    }
```

If you need more info in order to help me, please ask.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you care about "clean" URL in a first place? Does it break anything?

Comment: _"Also, display categories[]=125 is weird."_ - that is the result of submitting a form that has fields named with square brackets in the name, `name="categories[]"`. But you need those - you can't use a URL like `?categories=vocabulary&categories=grammar&categories=...`, because then PHP would _overwrite_ all those values with the last one. Plus, you would need to interfere with the submission of your form on the client side, if you wanted a different URL "format".

Comment: Why not just make it a POST request?

Comment: This is a simple GET request and I thought that the URL should look different, I don't know. I'm still a junior developer, so discovering things is what I do. I'll keep it like this, and see if a better solution, such as making it a POST request is better. Thanks for you comments!